# Solving process chaining in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to write a utility which will seamless pipe an unbounded amount of commands together in Python. This is what I've come up with so far, following [the documentation on piping in `subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def taskchain(argset, result=STDOUT):
    lastprocess = None

    for index, args in enumerate(argset): # expected to be a list containing lists
        process = Popen(args, stdout=stdout if index == (len(argset)-1) else PIPE,
            stdin=None if lastprocess is None else lastprocess.stdout)

        if lastprocess is not None:
            lastprocess.stdout.close()

        lastprocess = process

    if stdout == PIPE:
        return lastprocess.communicate()[0]
    else:
        lastprocess.wait()
```

Note that I'm not using `shell=True` in order to hopefully avoid security concerns there.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as I'm getting:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Baf file descriptor
```

I'm not sure what seems to be failing. Can someone help me write a method to implement process chaining for an unbounded amount of subprocesses?

(Use case is like this: `taskchain([('ps', 'aux'), ('grep', 'python'), ('cut', '-b', '1')])`.)

Comment: Style note: the `argset.index(args)` is something *I* really cannot watch... it hurts! If you iterate over the plain `argset` then you *shouldn't* need information on the indeces. If you only care of the indeces then use a `for i in range(len(argset)):` instead. If you need both(as in your case) then you *should* use `enumerate`!!! Note that `argset.index` might return the wrong index if there are equal elements why `enumerate` always return the correct index of the current `args`.

Comment: Refactoring accordingly.

Comment: have you seen [`plumbum`](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [`sh`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/)? It is *not* to discourage you, just to make you aware the packages exist.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, plumbum is awesome! It's nice to be aware of these libraries, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @ecatmur's help above, here's the final solution:

```
def taskchain(*args, **kwargs):
    output = kwargs.get('output', PIPE)
    error_output = kwargs.get('error_output', STDOUT) 
    lastprocess = None

    for index, argset in enumerate(args):
        islastprocess = index == len(args) - 1

        process = Popen(argset, stdout=output if islastprocess else PIPE,
                stdin=None if lastprocess is None else lastprocess.stdout,
                stderr=error_output)

        if lastprocess is not None:
            lastprocess.stdout.close()

        lastprocess = process

    if output == PIPE:
        return lastprocess.communicate()
    else:
        lastprocess.wait()
```

Processes are chained together, effectively emulating shell-based piping without the security risks!

Examples:

```
>>> print taskchain(('ps','aux'), ('grep','python'), ('cut','-c','1-50'))[0].trim()
naftuli   3221  0.1  0.1  60960 12376 pts/3    S+ 
naftuli   3242  0.0  0.0  32592  5748 pts/2    S+ 
naftuli   3246  0.0  0.0   9388   916 pts/2    S+ 
naftuli   5852  0.0  0.2 430284 20200 ?        Sl 
root      8153  0.0  0.1  95520 11060 ?        S

>>> print taskchain(('ls',), ('grep', 'ic'))[0]
Music
Pictures
Public
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stdout=stdout if argset.index(args) == (len(args) - 1) else PIPE)
```

This should probably be

```
stdout=stdout if argset.index(args) == (len(argset) - 1) else PIPE)
```

And you'd be better off using `enumerate` rather than `argset.index`.

Also, you need to connect the subprocesses to each other:

```
..., stdin=None if lastprocess is None else lastprocess.stdout)
```

Finally, `STDOUT` is only valid as an argument for the `stderr` parameter; to pass stdout through you should pass `stdout=None`.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same error, I'll update my question with the current code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by STDIN. The example in the Python documentation does it the same way as I'm currently doing it. Can you demonstrate what you mean by fixing it? The logic makes sense to me: if it's the last process, redirect output to where the user specifies, otherwise send it to PIPE.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay sorry, I meant `STDOUT`, not `STDIN`.  Passing `stdout=STDOUT` is an error, oddly enough.